# retaining specific sublist items from a list

Tags: python

Hi just a beginner in python. Could not figure out how to do this.
I have a list of polygon and its coordinates of vertices

list = [[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[1,3,3],[2,7,8],[2,9,9],[2,34,50],[3,6,0]]

The first item in each sublist is a identifier (polygon number) and the rest two are the values of that identifier or coordinates of the polygon.

I want to find the centroid of the polygon 1 and polygon 2. in case of polygon 3 there is only one coordinate so results in an error. How do i do this ?

Comment: What code do you have already?

Comment: I was able to separate out two lists from the parent list. One list contains the polygon identifiers and another contains the list of x and y coordinates. My challenge is how do i select x and y coordinates for all polygons whose  identifier is 1 and so on for calculation...

Comment: I would try this:

for i in list:
    if i[0]==1:
        for x in range(0,len(i)):
             if x==0:
                  continue
             print i[x] #this should be all the numbers printed for the last part of the string

Comment: It's a bad idea to call a variable "list" because that shadows the built-in name of the list type. Usually `list("abc")` would give `["a","b","c"]`, but it wouldn't after your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the points in a given polygon:

```
def get_polygon_points(polygon_id, points_list):
    return [(x, y) for i, x, y in points_list if i == polygon_id]
```

If you now write a `find_centroid` function that takes a list of coordinates (I'll leave that up to you), you can compose them together by writing something like this:

```
points_list = [[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[1,3,3],[2,7,8],[2,9,9],[2,34,50],[3,6,0]]
centroid_1 = find_centroid(get_polygon_points(1, points_list))
```